# During the decades leading up to the Great War, in which governments was realism highly concentrated?

Tags: political-theory, political-system, history

Searching the 1905-1915 period, and I have been so far unable to find much information concerning how realism affected the decision-making processes of countries at the time.

Which countries at this time (1905-1915) was realism the dominant philosophy (or at least a notable philosophy) in politics?

Comment: Are you looking for any specific continent or country? Do you have any decision in mind?

Comment: Mostly any countries that were known to be less oriented towards romanticism than rationalism.

Comment: By rationalism, I refer mostly to a lack of romanticism.

Comment: Realized my error with terminology and replaced "rationalism" with "realism"

Comment: Still not very helpful. “Realism” does have a specific meaning in foreign policy circles but that would be anachronistic in 1905-1915. “Romanticism” on the other hand is a 19th Century art movement, so what do you mean really?

Comment: Lack of romanticism? Off hand, I'd say likely none before 1914, given their views of armed conflict.

Comment: If this at all helps, political realism is often used interchangeably with the philosophy of realpolitik.